# Is there a way to utilize "color.from_gradient," in a "fill," as opposed to a "Plot?"

Tags: pine-script, fill

I want to produce a graduated fill to indicate the severity of an out-of-range plot.

The fill would be from the highest value = green to the lowest value = red.

I have a similar color.from_gradient working on several plots.  Can't find any documentation on using it as a fill.

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 0):

`color.from_gradient` only returns a single color. You can't use it paint a gradient. Unfortunately you can only do a stepped gradient like this :

```
bottom = close * 0.9
top = close * 1.1
interval = (top - bottom) / 4
level1 = bottom + interval
level2 = bottom + interval * 2
level3 = bottom + interval * 3

p1 = plot(bottom, color = na)
p2 = plot(level1, color = na)
p3 = plot(level2, color = na)
p4 = plot(level3, color = na)
p5 = plot(top, color = na)

fill(p1, p2, color = #330000FF)
fill(p2, p3, color = #770000FF)
fill(p3, p4, color = #BB0000FF)
fill(p4, p5, color = #FF0000FF)
```

You can do more than four obviously, and it should be "good enough", but won't look as nice as a proper graduated gradient.